# Python raw_input issue

Tags: python

Here's my code

```
def player_input():
    input = raw_input('Choose X or O')
    if input == "X":
        print input
    else:
        print 'Please choose an X or an O'
        player_input()

player_input()
```

Not sure why I'm getting this. No matter what I type, it seems to jump to the else statement.

Please Choose an X or an O
Choose X or O>? l
Please Choose an X or an O
Choose X or O>? X
Please Choose an X or an O
Choose X or O

Comment: Are you entering an uppercase X? Because I can't reproduce your problem. Copy pasting this code works. However, if you want consistency and you don't care about casing, then force your input to lowercase and check a single case.

Comment: Also cannot reproduce this. Are you sure you aren't entering in a space along with your `X`?

Comment: If this is the case, perhaps he want to test `input.upper().strip() == "X"` instead.

Comment: Apart from the comments above on why it does not work: Calling the function recursively seems a bad idea. Use a simple loop instead.

Comment: Thanks all! Turns out it was an issue with PyCharms interpreter :( As soon as I used the python interpreter on my OS it came out fine. My next issue is using the 'or' comparison. This -> if input == "x" or "X" or "o" or "O": yields  the result of only accepting lowercase x. Everything else jumps to the else statement. including X o and O

Answer (score -1):

To your second question answered in the comments

> Thanks all! Turns out it was an issue with PyCharms interpreter :( As soon as I used the python interpreter on my OS it came out fine. My next issue is using the 'or' comparison. This -> if input == "x" or "X" or "o" or "O": yields the result of only accepting lowercase x. Everything else jumps to the else statement. including X o and O – jmleczko

In python you have to use

```
if input == 'x' or input == 'X' or input == 'o' or input == 'O':
```

Python does not like it otherwise.
I recommend not to use `input` as a variable, since input is a system reserved function.

```
someInput = input("Enter here:")
>>> Enter here: ABC
print(someInput)
>>> ABC
```